# Filtering fibonacci sequence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fibonacci

I'm trying to filter a list that contains the Fibonacci numbers.

What I need is only odd numbers, and less or equal than `N`.

This is what I have so far:

```
fib   n | n == 0         = 0
        | n == 1         = 1
        | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibs n = [a | a <- [fib x | x <- [1..]], odd a, a < n]
```

That will give me what I want, but at the same time that solution won't work because I don't know ***how to stop*** retrieving elements from `fib` function. Of course, that is because of `x <- [1..]`.

I have thought about two options:

1. Placing a limit (that depends on `n`) in `x <- [1..]`
2. Defining `fibs` recursive so I can know when to stop (thought about it while writing the question)

**How could I do this?**

I'm not looking for an efficient way

**Edit:**
Here are the two solutions I had at the end:

```
fib   n | n == 0         = 0
        | n == 1         = 1
        | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibsAux n k xs  | a < n     = fibsAux n (k+1) (xs ++ [a])
                | otherwise = xs
                where 
                    a = fib k
fibs n = filter odd $ fibsAux n 0 []
```

and the one using the suggestion of @hammar:

```
fibs x = takeWhile (< x) [a | a <- [fib x | x <- [1..]], odd n]
```

Comment: it's already recursive, you meant iterative?

Comment: @ariel I meant defining it using more than a function body (using pattern matching, etc), instead of declaring it using list comprehensions. I'm talking about `fibs`, not about `fib`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [the `takeWhile` function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3atakeWhile) from  Data.List (and re-exported by the Prelude). For example,

```
takeWhile (< 4) [1..] == [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that even though the list is infinite, this terminates once it finds an element that does not satisfy the predicate.

Comment: @Oscar: [Here you go](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-List.html#takeWhile).

Comment: @luqui: It reminded me of [Project Euler #2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2). The whole point of PE is learning to figure out stuff on your own.

Comment: @hammar in fact, that's the problem I had to solve, but with a variable `n` instead of one million and I just omitted the sum ;) I'll edit my answer so you can see both solutions I had at the end.

Answer (score 6):

There's also a more efficient way to compute Fibonacci numbers:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Which can be filtered to give only the odd numbers:

```
oddFibs = filter odd fibs
```

Which can be truncated to less than or equal to N:

```
oddFibsLeN n = takeWhile (<= n) oddFibs
```