# iterate function not saving intermediate steps?

Tags: haskell, memoization

I just started learning Haskell, and as an exercise got into a Project Euler problem where Fibonacci numbers are summed. My current method is this function, which creates a new list with the next element:

```
fib :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
fib xs@(x1:x2:_) = (x1+x2) : xs
```

I found the function `iterate` which reapplies the function on it's result. However, the result is a list of lists, `[[2,1],[3,2,1],[5,3,2,1],..]`. What is the alternative to `iterate` when I'm not interested in the intermediate results? I want to do a `takeWhile` with a condition on the last generated number. Is this the wrong way to think about it altogether?

(I've seen better/shorter/niftier ways of generating the Fibonacci sequence, so I'm not really looking for feedback on the `fib` function - but I'd like to make it work, suboptimal method or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `iterate`! Because Haskell is a pure language, all of the sublists get shared and you pay essentially no cost for having generated all of those mini lists: `[2, 1]` is actually the `2, 1` in `[3, 2, 1]`, and so forth.

You don't really want a `takeWhile`, because that will give you a lot of extra gunk and you'll still need to get to the end of the list with `last`. Instead, use `find`.

Also note that if you're planning on summing the resulting list, you've missed a `1` so you'll be one off.

Comment: Interesting.. But how do you mean "use `find`"? I want to continue generating numbers until the generated number (ie the first element of the generated list) exceed some threshold. I don't know what the exact number generated is, so I can't search for it. The approach I tested was something like `takeWhile ((<t) $ head . last) ...`, but I couldn't get that to compile. (Oh, and the problem acually specifies 1, 2 as initial conditions, but thanks anyways :) )

Comment: `find` takes a boolean predicate (function of type `a -> Bool`) as its argument. In this case, `a` is the generated list, `[Int]`. So write a predicate that looks at the first element of a list and sees if it's greater than some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the use of `iterate`, but see [Filtering fibonacci sequence in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879415/filtering-fibonacci-sequence-in-haskell) for how to filter a list of fibs.

Is this the same homework assignment?

Comment: Hi! It's not a homework assignment, it's a Project Euler problem (http://projecteuler.net/) I decided to try to learn a bit. I found the `iterate` function to be interesting, so I wanted to know if I could use it for this.

Comment: Ah yes, you did say that in the original question and I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "take", since each successive approximation will be one integer more accurate than the last.  You can then do (head . reverse) on that.

Note that "every" result is an intermediate result if the function you are iterating doesn't have a computable fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

When needing a function in Haskell just define it :)

The folowing isn't the most elegant or idiomatic Haskell, but serves to show that you can always do things by hand with a tail recursive loop if the need arises

```
apply_n f n x =
    if n = 0 then x
    else apply_n' f (n-1) (f x)

n_th_fib n = apply_n fib n [1,1]
```

I'm pretty sure there is a neater way to do this using folds (or a library function I forgot about :) )